# Count line in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I try to count line in my SQL query.

It works without parameter. For example, if I assign directly `FIOForm = 'SmithJJ'`. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

> Exception: the SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

```cs
int kolNar = 0;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Name = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", System.Environment.UserName);

var pushStat = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reestr>("select  *  from Reestr where FIOForm = @Name and Status = 'Executed'", Name);

foreach (var u in pushStat)
{
    kolNar = pushStat.Count();
}

if (kolNar > 0)
    MessageBox.Show(kolNar.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can call:

```
Dispose();
```

before

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Name = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", System.Environment.UserName);
```

Comment: "SqlParameter" does not contain a definition for "Clear"

Comment: @Dyomp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: it would be Dispose() in this case.

Comment: I just shouldn't use 'foreach' here. Thanks everybody a lot. My stupid mistake:)